# List Interface implementation

Tags: java, collections, interface, dynamic-arrays

I have created in class a generic class that works like ArrayList. The class included an array that gets bigger and smaller by demand by functions. Now, I have to implement the List interface and got stuck on the Iterator and ListIterator. I get only errors all the time, when I try to realize methods that depends on Iterator or ListIterator. Of course I have searched on the internet but I think I miss something.

public class EviatarList implements List, Iterable {

```
private E[] arr;
private static final int DEFAULT_CAPACITY = 3;
private int index = 0;

private int iteratorIndex = 0;
```

```
@Override
public Iterator<E> iterator() {Iterator<E> it = new Iterator<E>() {
        @Override
        public boolean hasNext() {
            return index < arr.length && arr[index + 1] != null;
        }
        @Override
        public E next() {return arr[iteratorIndex++];}
        @Override
        public void remove(){
        E [] arr1 =(E[]) new Object [size()-1];
            try {
        arr[iteratorIndex] = null;
        iteratorIndex--;
        index--;
            for (int i = 0, j = 0; i < arr.length; i++, j++) {
                if (arr[i] != null)
                {
                    arr1[j] = arr[i];
                } else{
                    j--;
                }
            }
            } catch (Exception e)
            {
                System.out.println(e.getMessage());
            }
            arr = arr1;
        }
    };
    return it;
}
```

```
public ListIterator<E> listIterator() {
    ListIterator<E> li = new ListIterator<E>() {
        //o(1)
        @Override
        public boolean hasNext() {
            return index < arr.length;
        }

        //o(1)
        @Override
        public E next() {
            return arr[index++];
        }

        //o(1)
        @Override
        public boolean hasPrevious() {
            return index > 0;
        }

        //o(1)
        @Override
        public E previous() {
            return arr[index--];
        }

        //o(1)
        @Override
        public int nextIndex() {
            return iteratorIndex;
        }

        //o(1)
        @Override
        public int previousIndex() {
            return iteratorIndex--;
        }

        // o(n)
        @Override
        public void remove() {
            E[] newArr = (E[]) new Object[arr.length - 1];
            index--;
            for (int i = 0, j = 0; i < index; i++, j++) {
                if (i != iteratorIndex) {
                    newArr[i] = arr[j];
                } else {
                    j--;
                }
            }
            arr = newArr;
        }
```

Comment: "I get only errors all the time, whrn I try to realize methods that depands on Iterator or ListIterator" - so what errors are you getting? I notice you're trying to *use* a variable called `iteratorIndex` but I can't see where you're declaring it anywhere...

Comment: I just appended it, sorry.

Comment: But still no sign of what those errors are. Note that iterators are meant to be independent of each other - so it's inappropriate for `iteratorIndex` to be declared within the list itself.

Answer (score 1):

Sorry, but your question is a little vague so I cannot really answer. The implementation of `EviatarList` is not shown but used (e.g. `size()`) and "I get only errors all the time" is not clear about the kind of errors (from the compiler or runtime using it, ...).

Some thoughts on your implementation that may help one step further:

- Why you implement your own `List` instead of extending `AbstractList` (that would offer ready to use iterators)?
- You can have multiple iterators on the same collection, therefore the `iteratorIndex` has to be state (aka member) of the `Iterator`, not of the `List`!
- There is some confusion about `index` and `iteratorIndex` in your implementation. What is the difference and what is the role of `index`?
- As `ListIterator` extends `Iterator` it would simplify your implementation using the same for both:

  ```java
  public Iterator<E> iterator() {
    return listIterator();
  }
  ```